# How can I prepare an Inkscape SVG file for responsive web design?

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design, inkscape

I've been doing a tutorial on Treehouse on responsive web design. At this point in the tutorial we are asked to convert an image to an svg so it can scale fully responsively.

Rather than use Adobe Illustrator, which I don't own, I used the freeware Inkscape. Once the image is converted we are asked to open the image in a text editor and remove the height and width requirements from the svg declaration and add the object selector to our max width rule to our style css:

```
  img, object {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

However, after removing height and width the image is not responsive but instead oddly clipped like so:

[image]

Does anyone know what error I have made? Or what I should have removed?

Sorry if the question has been asked before, I can't find it.

edit1, the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   id="svg2985"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.4 r9939"
   width="319"
   height="177"
   sodipodi:docname="logo.gif">
  <metadata
     id="metadata2991">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs2989" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="640"
     inkscape:window-height="480"
     id="namedview2987"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.94984326"
     inkscape:cx="159.5"
     inkscape:cy="88.5"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="0"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg2985" />
  <image
     width="319"
     height="177"
     xlink:href="
```

It is the "height" and "width" in the first SVG tag that I have removed.

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: Look into css media queries, [link](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: There is missing code after `<image` but looks like you have an image in your svg that is not vectorial!

Comment: What you've created is an svg file that contains the original image raster. You've not done what the tutorial wants which is to convert the raster to a vector.

Comment: The missing code is 700 lines of the actual image data followed by:

     id="image2993"
     x="0"
     y="0" />
</svg>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The fact that you have just put a raster image in your SVG isn't the actual reason for what you are seeing.

All it means is that when the scaling of the SVG works properly (see below), you won't see the benefits of using vector artwork.  When you scale up vector artwork, you don't get the "jaggies" (blockiness) that you get when scaling up bitmaps.  If your SVG just contains a bitmap, it is pretty much the same as just using the bitmap.

The actual problem here is that Inkscape doesn't include a viewBox attribute in the SVGs it saves.

When you remove the "width" and "height" attributes, they default to "100%".  Which tells the browser to scale the SVG to fit the parent container.  Unfortunately for this scaling to work, the browser needs to know what the dimensions of the SVG content are.  That is what the viewBox attribute is for.

Illustrator adds the viewBox attribute, Inkscape does not.

To see what I mean, add the following to your `<svg>` tag after removing width and height:

```
viewBox="0 0 319 177"
```

You should find that your image is no longer clipped, and will resize when the page is resized.

Answer (score 37):

Inkscape  now provides an option to enable viewbox if you save the file as "optimized svg".
Very handy!

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature isn't yet available in the vanilla Mac or Windows clients as it requires a ubuntu python extension. You can hack it though ~> https://answers.launchpad.net/inkscape/+question/194132

Comment: Starting with 0.91, a viewBox is added automatically. It works!  See http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Tricks_and_tips#Scaling_images_to_fit_in_webpages.2FHTML

Answer (score 8):

As you can [read it here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18088/exporting-an-object-as-svg-from-inkscape) ( and for completing [qed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23768955/1581050)):

> 1. Select the object(s) to export
> 2. Open the document properties window ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
> 3. Select "Resize page to drawing or selection"
> 4. File > Save As Copy...
> 5. Select Optimized SVG as the format

Answer (score 0):

- You've done something wrong if you're "converting" raster to vector graphics. Not having used Inkscape, I can't say, but at least [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_raster-to-vector_conversion_software) it's not capable of performing conversions.
- You haven't converted anything, your image is in Graphics Interchange Format!

To see what a "real" SVG file looks like, open up the [example from the wiki page](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0_%D0%B2_SVG_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5.svg).

Comment: This is entirely possible - I only learnt about SVGs a couple of hours ago.

But it definitely says it has a .SVG extension. And I did change it by opening the original .gif  and then hiting file, save-as, and choosing .svg from the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Sorry it turned out to be such a silly mistake.

Comment: Inkscape has the handy "Trace Bitmap" tool that will create a new vector object based on an imported raster image

Comment: @rob Yes, I discovered that myself a couple years ago now. Handy in a pinch, but creates tons of cruff.